# Does speed.cloudflare.com have a JavaScript API for testing internet speed not in the cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, cloudflare, speed-test

I'm looking to create a client-side button that allows the user to test their internet speed. That internet speed will then be reported back to a spreadsheet using Google Sheets API. I really like Cloudflare's internet speed testing console, as well as their measurements, and was hoping that there's a way to use their service within my Node.js application.

I've looked at the following npm services already and do not find their apis adequate:

- `speed-cloud flare-cli` *Cannot use cli application inside JavaScript*
- `fast-speedtest-api` *Couldn't find token required to conduct speed test*
- `network-js` *Couldn't find functioning npm module*
- `network-speed` *Does not provide accurate information or enough info*
- `simple-url-speedtest` *Unable to run this service*
- `speedTest` *No versions available for speedtest*

Answer (score 2):

**@cloudflare/speedtest** is a JavaScript module to measure the quality of a client’s Internet connection. It's the measurement engine that powers the Cloudflare speedtest measurement application available at https://speed.cloudflare.com.

https://github.com/cloudflare/speedtest